# Разделить строку по символу

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. Возникла такая задача:

Таблица в БД.

```
id  color 
1   white,black 
2   green,red,yellow 
3   red,lavender
```

Необходимо получить для каждого id все цвета, которые ему соответствуют. Просто получить color - не проблема.

> $color = mysql_query("SELECT color
> FROM table WHERE id=$select_id");

Но надо не просто вывести весь список, а разделить его по запятой (','). То есть, чтобы получился массив, например для первого:

> $colors = ['white','black'];

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

explode(',', $var);

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

Comment: Спасибо. Именно это и надо.